# How to communicate from angular-material2 dialog to its parent

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

I have `Parent` component that opens an `angular-material2` dialog box.

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Child, {
            disableClose: true
        });
```

opened dialog `Child` component has a button 'Add'. I want to notify the `Parent' component if user click on 'Add' button.

How is this possible?

Comment: atleast give a reason for downvote

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I used `EventEmitter` to communicate back to parent container

```js
    // dialog component
    ...
    onAdd = new EventEmitter();
    
    onButtonClick() {
      this.onAdd.emit();
    }
    ...
```

and parent component

```js
    // parent component
    ...
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Component);
    const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe(() => {
      // do something
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      // unsubscribe onAdd
    });
    ...
```

Here is the demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/KbE3uQi2zMNaZlZEEG5Z

Thanks to [thomaspink](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3593#issuecomment-286392869)

Comment: Worked . Thanks

Comment: Thank you. that's work for dialog and master page communication. Also good example for understanding about emitters

Answer (score 14):

Your Answer is correct but this thing is already mentioned in Angular2 Material Documentation in a simple way as you can `subscribe` to `afterClosed` method of `dialog Reference` (dialogRef as in the example) and you will get the selected option's value from `subscribe` method's argument (In our case result ).

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.selectedOption = result;
});
```

For more details, you can visit this link https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog and go to **Example Tab** and try to understand simple example.

Comment: Your answer deserves an upvote, though in my case the accepted answer is right. I need to communicate with the parent module without closing the modal.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent is a service you can communicate via the service.

However you'll run into circular reference issues if they both reference each other. You can instead use the `data` parameter when you open the dialog to pass the 'parent' to it (I like to do this via an interface).

So in the component when you inject `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` you can specify it as a certain interface.

```
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IMainMenuDialogData
```

Then define that for whatever you're passing in.

```
export interface IMainMenuDialogData
{
    mainMenuService: MainMenuService;
}
```

In the 'parent' component you pass it in via the `data` property

```
this.dialogRef.next(this.dialog.open(MainMenuDialogComponent, {
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100%',
        data: <IMainMenuDialogData> { mainMenuService: this }  ....
```

If you don't like passing in the whole service you can pass in specific observables, or properties or whatever else you need.

Answer (score 1):

With "@angular/material": "~7.0.0" `componentInstance` no longer exist on MatBottomSheetRef.

It has been replace by `instance`

Parent implementation:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Component);
const sub = dialogRef.instance.onAdd.subscribe(() => {
  // do something
});
```