# How to communicate from mat dialog component to the component where mat dialog is implemented?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, mat-dialog

I have a dialog component and app component where the material dialog is implemented. 
**Here is the code of app component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {VERSION, MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import { DialogComponent } from '../dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  DialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>;
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  addItem() {
    this.DialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }

receiveMessageFromDialogComponent() {
  // how to receive message from dialog component
}
closeDialog(): void {
  this.DialogRef.close();
}
}
```

The dialog component is where the form is implemented, I need to take the form value and receive it in here. I tried using angular input and output to achieve this but dint work coz there is no child and parent communication. **Here is the Dialog component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>Add Item</h1>
    <mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Item name here...">
    </mat-form-field>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button (click)="saveMessage()">Add</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="closeDialog()">Cancel</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  `
})
export class DialogComponent {
  saveMessage() {
    console.log('how to send data to the app component');
  }
  closeDialog() {
    console.log('how to close');
  }
}
```

**[Working Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrzbgz?file=dialog.component.ts)**

Comment: Basically you want to pass your data from mat dialog form to you page where you came from right?

Comment: Yes. Thats what i asked in the question with code on stackblitz

Comment: could be nice if you can edit my stackblitz.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate from angular-material2 dialog to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717508/how-to-communicate-from-angular-material2-dialog-to-its-parent)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A use case scenario if you want to edit some data in a dialog then pass the edited data back to the component from the dialog. I used the example above but I consolidated the answer to make it easier to follow. Assuming the data is coming from a service this example shares data from a mat-dialog component to an app component in the same file.

```html
// app.component.html  

<div *ngFor="let a of appData">
  <p>{{a.name}}</p>
<button> (click)="open(event, a)">edit</button> 
</div>
```

```ts
// app.component.ts    

import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 appData: Array <any>;

 constructor(private dataService: DataService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}

 ngOnInit() {

   this.dataService.getData()
    .subscribe(res => { 
      //console.log(res);
      this.appData = res;
   })
 }

public open(event, data) {
  this.dialog.open(EditDialog, {
    data: data,
}).afterClosed()
  .subscribe(item => {
    // Edited Data sent to App Component from Dialog 
    console.log(item);
  });
 }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-dialog',
  template: `<span>Edit Data</span>
             <mat-dialog-content>
               <input matInput name="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Edit Name" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.name">
             </mat-dialog-content>
             <div>
               <span><button mat-raised-button (click)="updateData()">Update Recipe</button></span>
             </div>`,
 })

 export class EditDialog implements OnInit {

   dataItem: any;  

   constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef <EditDialog> , @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private dataService: DataService) {
     this.dataItem = this.data;
   }

   public updateData() {
     this.dialogRef.close(this.dataItem);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You can actually achieve communication using *subscription* to `@Output` through `MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>`. For some scenarios, you may need to get the data from a dialog before it is closed. Hence, we cannot make use of the `this.DialogRef.afterClosed()` function since we have to close the dialog first to get the data. Instead, we want to get the Component instance and access from there.

On your **DialogComponent**:

```
export class DialogComponent {
 
  @Output() submitClicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>){}

  saveMessage() {
    this.submitClicked.emit('Your data');
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

On your **AppComponent**:

```
openDialog() {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.submitClicked.subscribe(result => {
        console.log('Got the data!', result);
    });
}
```

Better make sure to `unsubscribe()` all your `Subscription`s. Something like this will do for a quick unsubscribe (if there's no validation of data involved):

```
const dialogSubmitSubscription = this.dialogRef.componentInstance.submitClicked
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Got the data!', result);
      // do something here with the data
      dialogSubmitSubscription.unsubscribe();
    });
```

Also, you can always close your dialog from the `AppComponent` with `this.dialogRef.close()` if you have to. Or in the example above, you can also use the `this.DialogRef.componentInstance.closeDialog()`.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer per this thread https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3593

Comment: Absolutely amazing and intuitive, thx bro

Answer (score 3):

A.  subscribe to the `afterClosed` Observable of `this.DialogRef`, you can add it after you call the `this.DialogRef.open` in app.component.ts  Like this

```
  addItem() {
    this.DialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
    this.DialogRef.afterClosed()
    .subscribe(return => console.log(return));
  }
```

B.  In `dialog.component.ts` import the MatDialog service, like this:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from'@angular/material';
```

C.  Make sure that the dialogRef is passed to your dialog constructor like this

```
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
```

C.  In the `saveMessage()` method, call the close dialog method and pass the value that you need to return to app component.

```
  saveMessage() {
    this.dialogRef.close('hello data');
  }
```

D.  App component will receive the value because it subscribe to the `afterClosed` dialog observable

Also take a look at the full example form [angular material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples)

Cheers

Comment: hi, can someone answer this question? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807800/angular-material-popup-windows-allow-windows-to-go-between-front-and-back